# Numpy identity values for ufunc maximum and minium

Tags: numpy

Why are `np.maximum.identity` and `np.minimum.identity` both equal to `None`? I would expect the identity of maximum to be `-np.inf` and `np.inf` for minimum. Using `None` as an operand to maximum/minimum returns an error, so there must be some internal translation?

Comment: `np.maximum.reduce([], initial=np.inf)`

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. The ```-np.inf``` identity will only work if the size of the array is bigger than 0 (not empty). So there is a special case for reducing arrays with no elements in ```np.maximum```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionally to the comments, the problem with `np.inf` is typing.
Indeed, if `-np.inf` would be used for the maximum, the result would be strange for integers and probably just wrong for structured types (actually, any non-floating-points types). Here is an example:

```py
empty = np.array([], dtype=np.int32)
print(np.maximum.reduce(empty, initial=-np.inf))
print(np.minimum.reduce(empty, initial=np.inf))
```

Which results in:

```
-2147483648
-2147483648
```