# why isn't the max of an empty numpy array negative infinity?

Tags: python, numpy

Calling `arr.max()` on an empty numpy array causes an error. But it's a common convention in math to say that the maximum of the empty set is negative infinity. And since numpy supports infinities, why doesn't `np.max()` behave this way? It would save me a couple lines of additional logic to handle empty arrays. I'm sure there's a good reason, just curious what that is.

Comment: I had a very similar question about this a while back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67425822/numpy-identity-values-for-ufunc-maximum-and-minium

Comment: What's wrong with routinely supplying the `initial` paramerer?

Comment: I suppose ```initial=-np.inf``` is helpful when the array type is ```float```. Didn't know about it before though, so thanks!